# Can I use Backbone with React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, backbone.js, reactjs, react-native

I have found several different examples of integrating React (View) with Backbone on the web, but not any to do the same with React Native. I was wondering if this was possible and also if there were any samples to play with.

This (https://github.com/magalhas/backbone-react-component) also seemed a good starting point, but since I don't have any knowledge, I am not sure if it can still be used in React Native.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be able to use some parts of Backbone, yes.

Backbone's views operate on the DOM in the web browser, and since React Native doesn't have that, you'll be unable to use Backbone view as-is.

However, notice that Backbone.React.Component is described as "a mixin that glues Backbone models and collections into React components". Therefore it works as the data layer of your application, supplying data to your view.

This would be useful in theory, but in practice I've just tried it and it doesn't actually work! That said, I did managed to tweak the code of Backbone.React.Component to fix it though, and this demo works:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var backboneMixin = require('backbone-react-component');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} = React;

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    mixins: [backboneMixin],
    render: function () {
        return <Text>{this.state.model.foo}</Text>
    }
});

var model = new Backbone.Model({foo: 'bar'});
model.set('foo', 'Hello world!');

var ReactNativeBackbone = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
        <View>
            <MyComponent model={model} />
        </View>
        );
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeBackbone', () => ReactNativeBackbone);
```

You will see the value of `foo` from the model shown on screen as "Hello world!". You will need to edit lib/component.js in Backbone.React.Component like this:

```
diff --git a/node_modules/backbone-react-component/lib/component.js b/fixed.js
index e58dd96..0ca09f7 100644
--- a/node_modules/backbone-react-component/lib/component.js
+++ b/fixed.js
@@ -32,7 +32,7 @@
   if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
     define(['react', 'backbone', 'underscore'], factory);
   } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
-    module.exports = factory(require('react'), require('backbone'), require('underscore'));
+    module.exports = factory(require('React'), require('backbone'), require('underscore'));
   } else {
     factory(root.React, root.Backbone, root._);
   }
@@ -70,11 +70,11 @@
     },
     // Sets `this.el` and `this.$el` when the component mounts.
     componentDidMount: function () {
-      this.setElement(React.findDOMNode(this));
+      //this.setElement(React.findDOMNode(this));
     },
     // Sets `this.el` and `this.$el` when the component updates.
     componentDidUpdate: function () {
-      this.setElement(React.findDOMNode(this));
+      //this.setElement(React.findDOMNode(this));
     },
     // When the component gets the initial state, instance a `Wrapper` to take
     // care of models and collections binding with `this.state`.
```

I made two changes:

- Require `React` instead of `react`
- Remove references to `findDOMNode`

I haven't done any extensive testing but this should get you started. I've also [opened an issue](https://github.com/magalhas/backbone-react-component/issues/81) to try and get the problem addressed in the main Backbone.React.Component code base.

Comment: Hi Colin, in your diff you are removing "this.setElement(React.findDOMNode(this));" and then adding it again, shall I just remove the whole line in the two functions?

Comment: woops, the diff was wrong. I've edited it. but yes, you could just deleted those lines rather than commenting.

Comment: I tried your way right now and what I get is: "{"type":"InternalError", "message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}.

Comment: I am having problems here: "packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/haste/DependencyGraph/index.js:229:13)", have you seen this already? thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens if you use "react" rather than "React" when using require - see the part of the diff that starts with "module.exports"

Comment: I was actually using "React", that's why it looked weird. Do you think I should relaunch xcode instead of cmd - r? The other thing is after changing the file I was getting that dependency issue in the terminal without even cmd + r.

Comment: Try closing the terminal window that the packager runs in then CMD+R (Run) in xcode

Comment: I have done as you say, but I am still getting this: http://pastebin.com/Z2NdjX4b

Comment: [SOLVED] I was editing the wrong component.js. Instead of looking at the node_modules within the app, I was changing the file in the npm dir. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [react-native-backbone](https://github.com/peter4k/react-native-backbone)